# Stream - Get activities from a stream of type 'notification' without aggregation

Tags: getstream-io

When a stream of type "notification" is created it has a default aggregation format of:

```
{{ verb.id }}_{{ time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}
```

Maybe I am getting this wrong, but when trying to get the latest activities like so:

```
const user = client.feed('notifications', userId);
const activities = await user.get();
```

I **don't need any aggregation**. All I want is to display the X latest activities that happened. How can I set the aggregation format to null (no aggregation at all, the call should just return an array order by the time of each activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable aggregation by setting the aggregation format to

`{{ id }}`

If you dont need notification counts you could also consider using a flat feed.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, but isn't this a hacky workaround? The result is still aggregated but each group has only one activity. Isn't there an API call to get activities but not divided into groups (even not a group of 1)?

Comment: No unfortunately not. If you want a flat feed that's an option. At the moment there's no way to have both a notification feed without aggregation. You can kinda disable it by using {{ id }} but that's the only option.

Comment: Ok... thanks! I really think this should be documented in Sentry docs, aorund "retriving activities".